# Angular 7 EventSource keeps fetching the stream indefinitely

Tags: angular

I'm using Spring Webflux on my server-side to return a `Flux` of objects. When I access the endpoint via the browser it works as expected, I get the 5 objects then the stream stops.

However when attempting to do it via Angular `EventSource` the stream seems stuck on 'repeat' for lack of a better word. How do I tell the `EventSource` to stop requesting more items when they've all been sent from the server?

The code is simple, but I've never used Angular for event sourcing before.

**Service:**

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class VideoSourceService {

  private videoDataSource: BehaviorSubject<Array<Video>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  videoData = this.videoDataSource.asObservable();

  startVideoStream(source: string) {
    const eventSource = new EventSource(source + "/videos");

    eventSource.addEventListener('message', message => {
      this.videoDataSource.next([...this.videoDataSource.value, JSON.parse(message["data"])]);
    });
  }
```

**Consumer:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-videos',
  templateUrl: './videos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./videos.component.scss']
})
export class VideosComponent implements OnInit {
  videos$: Observable<Video[]>;

  constructor(public videoSourceService: VideoSourceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.videoSourceService.startVideoStream(`${environment.apiUrl}`);

    this.videos$ = this.videoSourceService.videoData;
  }
}
```

and just for completeness, my backend method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "videos", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Video> getVideos() {

    return videoRepository.findAll();
}
```

As the backend works as expected in Chrome, I'm assuming the issue is somewhere with my Angular code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple issue, you need to manually close the connection when you're done with it.

```
  startVideoFavoriteStream(source: string) {
    //{...}

    eventSource.onerror = () => {
        eventSource.close();
    }
  }
```

does the trick.

Comment: So how can I get latest video list at Angular automatically when other users added videos through API because you close the event source.